# Location for the 32bit IDL Virtual Machine version [idlrt.exe ] in Windows registry?

Tags: registry, idl-programming-language

I have IDL 8.2 64bit version,
Which comes with 32bit version also,

I am looking for the 32bit IDL Virtual Machine version location [idlrt.exe ] in Windows registry:

But both these locations only refer to the 64bit version:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\idlrt.exe
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\idlrt.exe
```

Does anyone know where the location for the 32bit version is?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is stored in the registry. I just did a search and couldn't find any mention of the 32-bit idlrt.exe.